# Speedup Windows C Port Scanner

Tags: c, windows, performance, winapi, port-scanning

So I developed a port scanner for C on windows but I have noticed on some IP's it runs very slowly. Here's my code for it:

```
DWORD WINAPI connectPortW(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    HANDLE hStdout;
    PMYDATA pDataArray;

    WSADATA firstsock;
    SOCKET s;
    struct sockaddr_in sa;
    int err;

    char * openPorts = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*256);
    memset(&openPorts[0], 0, strlen(openPorts));

    hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    if(hStdout == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
    {
        return 1;
    }

    pDataArray = (PMYDATA)lpParam;

    strncpy((char *)&sa,"",sizeof sa);  
    sa.sin_family = AF_INET;

    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0),&firstsock) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"WSAStartup() failed"); 
        exit(1);
    }

    sa.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(pDataArray->ip); 

    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); //make net a valid socket handle
    if(s < 0)
    {
        perror("\nSocket creation failed");  // perror function prints an error message to stderr
        exit(1);
    }

    sa.sin_port = htons(pDataArray->port);
    err = connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, sizeof sa);

    //connection not accepted
    if(err == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("%s %-5d Winsock Error Code : %d\n", pDataArray->ip, pDataArray->port, WSAGetLastError());
        strcpy("NULL", openPorts);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    //connection accepted
    else
    {
        printf("%s %-5d accepted            \n", pDataArray->ip, pDataArray->port);
        sprintf(openPorts, "%i,", pDataArray->port);
        if(shutdown(s, SD_BOTH ) == SOCKET_ERROR )
        {
            perror("\nshutdown");
            exit(1);   
        }
   } 
   closesocket(s); 

   fflush(stdout);

   strcpy(pDataArray->openPorts, openPorts);

   free(openPorts);

   return 0;
}
```

Keep in mind I already use threads and each thread calls this function for a different port (0 - 1024) on the same IP.

So how can I speed this up? I keep seeing people talking about non-blocking, would that speed it up and if so how can I implement that. Thanks!

Edit: It is taking 614 seconds (10 minutes) to scan from 0 - 1024 on one of the aforementioned 'slow' ip's

Edit 2: I started trying to use non-blocking... Am I doing this right?

```
ioctlsocket(s, FIONBIO, &on);
connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, sizeof sa);
FD_ZERO(&fds);
FD_SET(s, &fds);

err = select(s, &fds, &fds, &fds, &tv);

if (err != SOCKET_ERROR && err != 0)
{
    sprintf(openPorts + strlen(openPorts),"%i,", pDataArray->port);
}
closesocket(s);
```

Edit 3: It seems this new method is giving me inaccurate results but much much faster. I seem to be getting more open ports then compared to the results of running nmap on the same IP.

Comment: Do you know what your bottlenecks are? Have you profiled it?

Comment: No I have no idea what is bottlenecking it, how could I go about figuring out whats bottlenecking it?

Comment: using asynchronous io you can not speed up reply from some specific ip. this at all not depend from your code. but using asynchronous io - you can make your code much more effective and less resource use. 1024 threads ?? this is nightmare. with asynchronous io you using only thread pool with fixed count of threads (usual one thread per core)

Comment: I only use 20 threads at a time

Comment: 1024 threads a nightmare?  The box I'm using to post this has 1037 threads in existence ATM, according to TM.

Comment: you are not using `select()` correctly.  You have to use a different `fd_set` for each parameter, and you have to handle the return value correctly. `-1` on `select` error, `0` on timeout, `> 0` on socket event. Note the `exceptFD` parameter will indicate a `connect` error, so `select()` will return > 0 in that case. Use `getsockopt(SO_ERROR)` to get the actual error code. Also, writing to `pDataArray->openPorts` is not thread-safe if multiple threads share the same buffer, so synchronize access to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a lot of problems with your thread code:

- it is leaking memory if a failure happens.
- You are misusing `strlen()` when calling `memset()` on your `openports` variable.  Just remove the `memset()` altogether and use `calloc()` or `LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT)` instead when allocating `openports`. Or, just use the call stack instead, since the variable is small: `char openPorts[256] = {0};`  Or better, don't even use a local `openports` variable at all, simply write to `pDataArray->openPorts` directly when you have a result available.
- You should not be using `exit()` at all.  Use `return` instead.
- it is not technically illegal to call `WSAStartup()`/`WSACleanup()` multiple times, since WinSock is reference counted, however it is best to call them only once at program startup/exit, not per thread.  But, since you are calling `WSAStartup()`, you *must* call `WSACleanup()` to keep the WinSock reference count balanced.
- What are you trying to do with `strcpy("NULL", openPorts);`? You are writing to read-only memory.  I think you mean `strcpy(openPorts, "NULL");` instead.
- writing to `pDataArray->openPorts` is not thread-safe if multiple threads are sharing a single buffer (your use of `,` in your `sprintf()` string implies that may be the case). You need to synchronize access to the buffer when writing to it across multiple threads. you can use a critical section or mutex for that purpose.

That being said, you are using a blocking socket, so `connect()` will block the thread until WinSock times out internally, which may take awhile on slow networks.  To speed it up, switch the socket to non-blocking mode using `ioctrlsocket(FIONBIO)`, and then use `select()` to implement your own timeout for `connect()`, eg:

```
DWORD WINAPI connectPortW(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    PMYDATA pDataArray = (PMYDATA) lpParam;

    HANDLE hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    if (hStdout == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return 1;

    WSADATA wsa;
    int err = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0), &wsa);
    if (err != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s %d WSAStartup() failed, Error Code : %d\n", pDataArray->ip, pDataArray->port, err);
        return 1;
    }

    SOCKET s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); //make net a valid socket handle
    if (s == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s %d Socket creation failed, Error Code : %d\n", pDataArray->ip, pDataArray->port, WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    u_long enabled = 1;
    if (ioctlsocket(s, FIONBIO, &enabled) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s %d Socket non-blocking mode failed, Error Code : %d\n", pDataArray->ip, pDataArray->port, WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(s);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in sa = {0};
    sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sa.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(pDataArray->ip); 
    sa.sin_port = htons(pDataArray->port);

    if (connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, sizeof sa) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        err = WSAGetLastError();
        if (err != WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s %d Socket connect failed, Error Code : %d\n", pDataArray->ip, pDataArray->port, err);
            closesocket(s);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        fd_set wfd, efd;

        FD_ZERO(s, &wfd);
        FD_SET(s, &wfd);

        FD_ZERO(s, &efd);
        FD_SET(s, &efd)'

        timeval timeout;
        timeout.tv_sec = 5;
        timeout.tv_usec = 0;

        err = select(0, NULL, &wfd, &efd, &timeout);
        if (err == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s %d Socket select failed, Error Code : %d\n", pDataArray->ip, pDataArray->port, WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(s);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        if (err == 0)
        {
            // connect timeout
            closesocket(s);
            WSACleanup();
            return 0;
        }

        if (FD_ISSET(s, &efd))
        {
            err = 0;
            getsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, (char*)&err, sizeof err);
            closesocket(s);
            WSACleanup();

            switch (err)
            {
                case WSAETIMEDOUT: // connect timeout
                case WSAECONNREFUSED: // port closed
                    return 0;
            }

            fprintf(stderr, "%s %d Socket connect failed, Error Code : %d\n", pDataArray->ip, pDataArray->port, err);
            return 1;
        }
    }

    // connected!
    printf("%s %d accepted\n", pDataArray->ip, pDataArray->port);

    // note, this is not thread-safe! Need to sync access to openPorts...
    sprintf(pDataArray->openPorts + strlen(pDataArray->openPorts), "%d,", pDataArray->port);

    closesocket(s); 
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your example helped a ton. Now if I want to make the timeout shorter do I change timeout.tv_sec = 5 to something less like 3 or 2?

Comment: @JustinBraham: yes.  [Read the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740560.aspx).